# How do I output the child of a child using a Rabl API in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rabl

I have three tables -- stores, addresses and sales.  Each store has one or more addresses.  Each store also has one or more sales.  These relationships are defined in my models.  I have a Rabl API that is returning information about sales.  I can easily access the store information by using child as follows:

```
object @sales

attributes :name, :description

child :store do
    attributes :id, :name
end
```

However, how do I access the addresses information pertaining to that store? There is no direct relationship between sales and addresses specified in the model; the relationship is between stores and addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can nest your child elements like so

```
object @sales

attributes :name, :description

child :store do
    attributes :id, :name

    child :addresses do 
        attributes :id, :address, :city, :state
    end
end
```

see 'Deep Nesting' at https://github.com/nesquena/rabl